# Ignore character in xml element

Tags: c++, xml

I'm trying to emulate a gamemode, and I'm currently writing the functions to read the xml. Everything is reading correctly, except this portion of the xml.

```
<UPGRADE
    requireHonor="250:325:400:1200" dps="40:60:80:200" magazineSize="0.5:0.75:1.0:3.0" 
    <!--The magazineSize is multiplied by the size of the magazine & then added to the original size.-->
/>
```

Is there a specific way that I could ignore the colons inbetween the numbers?Apologies if this question has already been asked, but I wasn't able to find anything that quite matched this.

Example of how I tried to read with sscanf:

```
            if (!stricmp(szAttrName, "requireHonor"))
            {
                sscanf(szAttrValue, "%d:%d:%d:%d", &pUpgrade->nrequireHonor[0], &pUpgrade->nrequireHonor[1],
                    &pUpgrade->nrequireHonor[2], &pUpgrade->nrequireHonor[3]);
            }
            else if (!stricmp(szAttrName, "dps"))
            {
                sscanf(szAttrValue, "%d %d %d %d", &pUpgrade->ndps[0], &pUpgrade->ndps[1], &pUpgrade->ndps[2],
                    &pUpgrade->ndps[3]);
            }
            else if (!stricmp(szAttrName, "magazineSize"))
            {
                sscanf(szAttrValue, "%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f", &pUpgrade->fmagazineSize[0], &pUpgrade->fmagazineSize[1],
                    &pUpgrade->fmagazineSize[2], &pUpgrade->fmagazineSize[3]);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dps format string should be `"%d:%d:%d:%d"` just like you did with requireHonor, and your magazineSize format string should be `"%f:%f:%f:%f"` with colons.  You need the colons to anchor the parsing, and for parsing floats, just `%f` is enough.

Comment: Ahh ty for pointing out that I didn't do it on the other 2 attributes, everything's reading correctly now. Much appreciated, can be so easy to miss that when you have upwards of 1200 lines to look at haha.